# Font sizes as classes in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to apply a class instead of a size when the user selects a font size. According to the docs this should be enough but it doesn't work:

```
font_size_classes : 'fXXS,fXS,fS,fN,fL,fXL,fXXL'
```

If I use:

```
fontsize_formats: 'XXS=1 XS=2 S=3 N=4 L=5 XL=6 XXL=7',        
font_size_classes : 'fXXS,fXS,fS,fN,fL,fXL,fXXL'
```

The new titles appear in the combo but when I select it it doesn't apply the class.

How can I make it work? I just need something like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can offer this

```
style_formats: [
{title: 'Small', inline: 'span', styles: {fontSize: '10px'}},
{title: 'Normal', inline: 'span', styles: {fontSize: '14px'}},
{title: 'Large', inline: 'span', styles: {fontSize: '18px'}},
{title: 'Huge', inline: 'span', styles: {fontSize: '24px'}},
```

],
[image]

font_size_classes is in tinymce 3.x.This option is only used when the convert_fonts_to_spans option is enabled.

```
convert_fonts_to_spans:true,
```

[Look at here](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:font_size_style_values)

Comment: I need to set a class for each size. I can't set absolute font sizes.

Comment: Thanks, that was my first try (using classes instead of styles) but in this case if I activate a size, the others don't deactivate, which doesn't make sense. I'll upvote anyways because it's useful, although not what I'm looking for